# Is it possible to define anaphoric macros using syntax-rules only?

Tags: macros, scheme, syntax-rules

Is possible to write [anaphoric macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) (e.g. `aif`) using `syntax-rules` only? Such a macro would need to break the hygiene of the macro system. I know that this is possible with `syntax-case`, but is it somehow possible with `syntax-rules` in R5RS and R7RS-small? If so, could you supply a minimal example that implements "anaphoric if" (`aif`) using `syntax-rules` only?

Comment: [Kiselyov 2013 How to Write Seemingly Unhygienic and Referentially Opaque Macros with Syntax-rules](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/Dirty-Macros.pdf)

Comment: syntax-rules + [SRFI-139 syntax parameters](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-139/srfi-139.html) can do it.